# How to reset Ubuntu that is dual booted

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have recently dual-booted Ubuntu to run alongside Windows 8.1 and now both are pretty slow and laggy.

I have a 500 GB HDD and I gave equal amounts of space to both (250 GB each) and now I want to give Ubuntu more space. I want to do a clean reset of Ubuntu and give it more space. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: *"both are pretty slow, laggy, and overall just crappy"* - Methinks either you have an underpowered CPU/GPU, you need more RAM, or both.

Comment: I am using a sony laptop with 4GB ram and an intel pentium CPU, built in graphics card. It use to run pretty smoothly (so smooth that I could record some Minecraft). Is there anyway I could do a clean reinstall of ubuntu and have it still duel-booted?